# Is an .apk file enough to install application to my Android phone?

Tags: android, apk

I'm testing an Android application I'm developing, and I want to install it to my phone some place else. (i.e. not by plugging it with a USB cable to the PC where Eclipse is installed)

Can I send the *.apk file to my e mail and download the file at home, and install it to my device?

Comment: Yes.. in gmail you get install option directly..

Comment: Before install *.apk file you should go to securite and set chekbox for unknown source

Comment: This is not a programming question it belongs on StackExchange or some other sister site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to understand what is APK file.

Android application package file (APK) is the file format used to distribute and install application software and middleware onto Google's Android operating system.APK files are ZIP file formatted packages based on the JAR file format, with .apk file extensions.For more info check out [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29).

Hence it is enough for you to copy apk file for installing the App.And dont forgot to allow apps from unknown sources.For that process check [here](http://gameolith.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/76902-android-4-0-tablets-allowing-app-installs-from)

Answer (score 2):

Some easy steps:

1. Download the APK files from [somewhere](http://www.droidpick.com).
2. Go to your android device setting -> Security -> check the "Unknown sources" is ON.
3. You are ready to go! Install your APK files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can install apk in to the device. But make sure that Install app from `unknown sources` to be enabled in the settings of the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes apk file is enough to install in any android device.

Answer (score 0):

yes,apk file is enough to install in device